# Unit tests for web app with multiple databases

Tags: mysql, django, database, postgresql, unit-testing

I have a django web application which uses two databases: MySQL and PostgreSQL. I want to run some unit tests which check for object creation and reading them for models in the PostgreSQL database. While I run them, the test database is not getting created with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'jsonb NULL, `processed_payload` jsonb NULL, `scheduled_time` datetime(6) NULL, `' at line 1")
```

My settings.py file has the database entries like the following (putting alias instead of actual values):

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'name_1',
    'USER': 'user_1',
    'PASSWORD': 'user_pwd_1',
    'HOST': 'host_1',
    'PORT': '3306',
},
'payouts': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'name_2',
    'USER': 'user_2',
    'PASSWORD': 'user_pwd_2',
    'HOST': 'host_2',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

How can I make sure that the database is created for PostgreSQL instead of MySQL so that the create table query does not fail?

Edit:
Including the APIRouter I created to manage the database selection while running the application.

```
class APIrouter(object):

    payouts_tables = ['PayoutsConfig', 'PayoutStructures']

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model.__name__ in self.payouts_tables:
            return 'payouts'
        else:
            return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model.__name__ in self.payouts_tables:
            return 'payouts'
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if model.__name__ in self.payouts_tables:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'payouts':
            return db == 'payouts'
        return None
```

Also including the unit test snippet that I tried to run:

```
class PayoutsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        conf = {"key": "value"}
        config = PayoutsConfig.objects.create(config_name="unit_test_config_1",payout_type=1,payout_config=conf)
        structure = PayoutStructures.objects.create(structure_name="unit_test_1", payout_configurations=[config])

    def test_structure_name(self):
        structure = PayoutsConfig.objects.get(structure_name="unit_test_1")
        self.assertEqual(structure.name, "unit_test_1")
```

The models used in this test are the following:

```
class PayoutsConfig(models.Model):
    config_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    payout_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PayoutTypes.payout_type_choices,null=True)
    payout_config = JSONField(null=True)

class PayoutStructures(models.Model):
    structure_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    payout_configurations = models.ManyToManyField('PayoutsConfig', related_name='structures')
```

Comment: have you created a custom database router?

Comment: I have created an APIRouter that is also setup in settings file. My application is working fine functionally.

Comment: post that router please and also the model in question

Comment: Included with an edit.